# Metaplectic and Bipartite representations of SL(2,R)

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I have a question about two different oscillator representations of the group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. By oscillator representation I mean one using creation and annihilation operators. I want to know if they are equivalent or not. Here are the two representations
\begin{equation}
  B^0 = \frac{a^{\dagger}a - b^\dagger b}{2},\quad
  B^- = \frac{a^2-(b^{\dagger})^2}{2},\quad
  B^+ = \frac{(a^\dagger)^2-b^2}{2},\quad
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  L^0 = \frac12 (a_1^\dagger a_1 + a_2^\dagger a_2 + 1),\quad
  L^+ =  a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger,\quad
  L^- = a_1 a_2,
\end{equation}
where every oscillator $a,b,a_1,a_2$ has the standard commutation relation
\begin{equation}
  [a,a^\dagger] = 1,\quad [b,b^\dagger] = 1, \quad [a_i,a_j^\dagger] = \delta_{ij},
\end{equation}
and the commutators of different oscillators are all zero. One can check that those two representations indeed form the $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ algebra.
\begin{equation}
 [X^-,X^+] = 2X^0, \quad [X^0,X^-] = -X^-, \quad [X^0,X^+] = X^+,
\end{equation}
where $X$ can be $B$ or $L$. The question then is, is there any map $(a,b) \leftrightarrow (a_1,a_2)$ that maps the $B$ operators into the $L$ ones. For example my first guess was
\begin{align}
  a &= \frac{a_1+a_2}{\sqrt{2}},\\
  b^\dagger &= \frac{a_1-a_2}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{align}
which indeed maps $B^\pm$ into $L^\pm$. However the $[b,b^\dagger]$ commutator has the wrong sign and the $B^0$ operators does not map into $L^0$. If anyone has any idea it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!